# installing IIS on windows 10 uisng Turn windows features on or off

Tags: iis, windows-10

I am trying to install IIS on windows 10 but when I go to control panel => Programs and Features =>Turn windows features on or off, the windows opens with none of the features like this:

[image]

Please suggest me why I can't see the programs?

Thanks.

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More info is available in the [help] if you need it.

Comment: Fix to all weird windows problems ... Reboot!